# NSNetService: Handle name conflicts when publish service

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservice

According to the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html) :

> If that service name conflicts with an existing service on the network, Bonjour chooses a new name. ...  your service is automatically renamed if it conflicts with the name of an existing service on the network

How can I achieve this function?

My implementation:

```
self.publishService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_http._tcp." name:@"MyName" port:80];
self.publishService.delegate = self;
[self.publishService publish];

- (void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender {
    NSLog(@"did publish: %@", sender.name);
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
    NSLog(@"did not publish: %@", errorDict);
}
```

When this service is already published the `didNotPublish` delegate method will be called. I assume the service won't be published?

I thought that the `netServiceDidPublish:` delegate method should be called again for the service with the new name, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the port, not the name.

If there is a name collision, it automatically renames the service by appending `" (2)"` to the name, increasing the number as far as it needs to.  In this case it will publish successfully and call `netServiceDidPublish:`.

If the port is already used by another published service it won't publish it, and will call `netService:didNotPublish:` with the error dictionary set to `NSNetServicesErrorCode = 48; NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 1;`.

Comment: Thank you! When creating the NSNetService instance I changed the port to 0: `self.publishService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:self.serviceIdentifier name:self.bonjourName port:0];`. I also have to change the publish method to `[self.publishService publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections];`.